# QFileDialog: How to open/select file/dir from package in osX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, package, qfiledialog

I have googled a lot but dint find any relative solution for my problem.

**PROBLEM:** I want to open `.MTS` file and its working find if its available in any `directory`. But if its in any `package` then my `QFileDialog` is not able to look into that package and select those `.MTS` files.

**CODE:**

```
auto filePaths = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this, "Open Video File", lastOpenedPath, "*.MTS;*.mov");
    qDebug() << "File Paths " << filePaths;
```

Now the `.MTS` files created under `AVCHD(Advanced Video Coding High Definition)` package default in Sony & Panasonic HD Camera, and I want to import/select that `.MTS` files.

**HINT:** `QFileDialog` is able to import/select those `.MTS` files in Windows machine, but fail to import/select in mac machine.

Highly appreciated any thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of a **full file path** to an .MTS file you _can_ open in your dialog and the **full file path** to an .MTS file you currently can't open but would like to? I want to make sure I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I understand what you want to do properly, I'm not sure that it's possible in Qt alone.

It did turn out to be easier than I expected to simply call in to Cocoa and `NSOpenPanel` to achieve what I think you're looking for.

Sample project is at: https://github.com/NSGod/widgetsOpenFileDialogCocoa

Basically, I renamed `mainwindow.cpp` to `mainwindow.mm`, then added an `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

void MainWindow::on_openFileButton_clicked()
{
    NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mts", @"mov", nil]];
    [openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
    [openPanel setTreatsFilePackagesAsDirectories:YES];
    [openPanel setTitle:@"Open Video File"];

    NSInteger result = [openPanel runModal];

    QStringList stringList;

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSArray *URLs = [openPanel URLs];
        NSLog(@"URLs == %@", URLs);
        for (NSURL *URL in URLs) {
            stringList += QString::fromNSString(URL.path);
        }
        // do something with stringList
        qDebug() << "filePaths == " << stringList;
    }
}
```

Included in the project is a `fakeBundle.component` directory, which will be treated as a bundle (or "package") by OS X. But by setting `treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories` to YES, you can have the `NSOpenPanel` treat it as a directory (which it really is, of course).

Here is an image showing how the Finder treats this `fakeBundle.component` directory as if it were a single file:

[image]

And here in the `NSOpenPanel`, it's being treated as a directory:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's great to have qualification on how this *can* be accomplished in OSX. I'd commented, and perhaps I should include it in the answer, that you can't do this with just Qt/C++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595747/qfiledialog-how-to-open-select-file-dir-from-package-in-osx/36596238?noredirect=1#comment60794028_36596238 This answer provides a tremendous stepping off point for how to accomplish this. +1

Comment: @NSGod : Thanks, Its work for me. Now can able to look into bundle and select `.MTS` file. +1

Answer (score 1):

[An OSX package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_(OS_X)) is a:

> File system directory that is normally displayed to the user by the Finder as if it were a single file. Such a directory may be the top-level of a directory tree of objects stored as files, or it may be other archives of files or objects for various purposes, such as installer packages, or backup archives.

This is akin to an [.mst or .msi file on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer). Just as with OSX packages you would not be able to open your specified file within one of these packages. Your system open dialog is in fact doing you a *disservice* by allowing you to see into them, as you cannot open said files.

Your work around is to copy the file out of the package externally to the program then open the copy of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's what I am currently doing. "copy the file out of the package externally to the program then open the copy of the file", But is there any other solution ? Can I restrict to open `AVCHD` package/ any package only?

Comment: @ABBolim First off your file open dialog shouldn't allow you to see inside packages: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/768 so there must be something afoot. Secondly, I think your best bet is providing drag and drop support. So that someone can navigate into the package externally to your program then drag the file's icon, dropping it on your program, thereby causing OSX to do the decompression for you.

Comment: OK. Got it. But can file dialog allow to select any package ? So that using path of that package and extract that package at run time and select those `.MTS` files from that specific package.

Comment: @ABBolim If you look at the packages in the command prompt they will have an extension, you'd need to add that to your `QFileDialog` specifier. But that isn't going to get you all the way there, you'll also need to find a library to extract files from a package, and as you're probably aware, such questions are [beyond the scope of http://www.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)

Comment: Thanks for you response +1.

Comment: @JonathanMee: you're misunderstanding what an OS X package is. There are 2 senses: an installer package, which is basically an archive file which is akin to the installer files on Windows, but the other sense is in the sense of "package/bundle/" which is the sense the OP means here. `NSSavePanel` (which is what the Open/save interface is based on) defines a `treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories` property: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSSavePanel/treatsFilePackagesAsDirectories

Comment: In other words, it is perfectly possible to be able to look inside packages and open the files (as read only). If there is any chance you want to modify the file, always make a copy of it elsewhere and work with that, as otherwise you could invalidate the code signature of the app (if it's codesigned). There is no decompression or anything being taken place, as this truly is a directory (folder) that contains files. It's just the Finder which "pretends" like it's a single file. You can peak inside though: http://superuser.com/a/414516/56812

Comment: @NSGod I understood that it was compressed, but from your explanation it sounds as though we can still open it like a read-only file. I didn't know that. Is there some trick to doing that? Perhaps you should write your own answer?

Comment: @JonathanMee: the trouble is, I know very little about Qt, so at this point, the answer wouldn't amount to much beyond "it should be possible, as the underlying OS supports it, but how to accomplish it in Qt, I don't know. Here's how I would do it in Cocoa (Objective-C)....". I have Qt on my system and will look at the source when I get a chance...